# HTML5 Audio - How to detect if a file is supported

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers

Using HTML, [I can write this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This will first try to play horse.ogg, and if it isn't supported, then it will play horse.mp3. My question is, is it possible to do something like this using `new Audio()` (i.e. without touching the DOM)? For example, this is what I was thinking:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "horse.ogg";
audio.load();
if (!audio.canPlay) {
    audio.src = "horse.mp3";
    audio.load();
}
```

I know of [these techniques](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#audio-mp3), but they assume that I know the type of file that is being sent in. Though I could do an extension check, it seems very hacky.